# Is there an adjective for food being difficult to chew?

Tags: word-request, food

I would like to say something like this:

> The beef is so difficult-to-chew-y that I can barely chew it.

But I can't find a proper word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about *stringy*, *tough*, *rubbery*, *leathery*, *sinewy* or *gristly*?

Comment: There's also *chewy*, but that can be used positively as well as negatively.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're probably looking for is "hard" or "ropy". If you're talking about food you could describe it being expired, as some foods go rock hard when they've been left out.